# Custom database class with Mysqli, cannot get error after query

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, require

I have the following class

```
class mydbclass extends MySQLi {

public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {

    parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        $this->greh(mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}


function mquery($sql){

    if(!($result = $this->query($sql)))
    {

        $emsg = $this->error;
        $enum = $this->errno;
        echo 'Error with msg: ' . $emsg . ' and num: ' .$enum;

    } else {
        echo 'ok';
    }
}}
```

If I call it from the same file ('mdb.php') it's working fine.

However if I require it in let say index.php, it's not catching the error msg and num.

I spend a lot of time here and on google and I'm unable to understand this behavior.

Here's the code in index.php:

```
require_once ('databasecontrol.php');
$db = new mydb('127.0.0.1', 'x', 'x', 'x');
$db->mquery($sqlt);
```

Comment: Show the code. **How** do you call it from index.php? You also need to check for `connect_error` in the constructor

Comment: your class is called `mydbclass` while you're creating new `mydb`. which one you calling?

Comment: it's a typo, I'm calling mydbclass....